# For loop for PowerShell

Tags: powershell, loops, batch-file, for-loop, scripting

I have a batch script but I want to make the same for PowerShell

This is my batch script loop:

```
for /F "tokens=1" %%z in ('%MYSQL% -U postgres -l ^| findstr "beheer forms loket kcs mo alfresco"') do (
    echo Dumping database %%z
    %MYPGDUMP% -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -f "% %%%z".backup %%z 
)
)
```

Now I need the same, but for PowerShell. So far I have this:

```
$database=Set-Location 'E:\Exxellence\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\';
.\psql --% -U postgres -l | Out-String -Stream | Select-String -Pattern "beheer"

foreach ($database in $database) {
    Set-Location 'E:\Exxellence\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\';
    .\pg_dump --% -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -f "$database.backup"
}
```

Comment: Maybe start with posting what you tried with powershell until now?

Comment: Have something like this.


$database=Set-Location 'E:\Exxellence\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\';
.\psql --% -U postgres -l | Out-String -Stream | Select-String -Pattern "beheer"

ForEach ($database in $database)
{
Set-Location 'E:\Exxellence\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin\';
.\pg_dump --% -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -f "$database.backup"
}

Comment: Please edit your question and insert the code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple issues with your PowerShell code:

- `Set-Location` doesn't return any output, so the variable `$database` is empty.
- `foreach ($database in $database)`

  You're using the same variable that *should* hold the list of databases as the loop variable. Use a different variable as the loop variable. Also, since `$database` is empty (see above), PowerShell will simply skip over the loop.
- You need to extract the database names from the `psql` output, otherwise you'll get the entire line (including information about owner, encoding, etc.).
- The "magic operator" `--%` stops PowerShell from parsing the rest of the commandline, so your variable `$database` in the output filename won't be expanded.
- You didn't specify the database name in the `pg_dump` commandline.

Change your code to something like this:

```bsh
Set-Location 'E:\Exxellence\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin'
$databases = (.\psql -U postgres -l) -match '^ \S' | ForEach-Object {
    ($_ -split '\s+\|\s+')[0].Trim()
} | Where-Object {
    $_ -match '^(beheer|forms|loket|kcs|mo|alfresco)$'
}

foreach ($db in $databases) {
    .\pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -f "${db}.backup" $db
}
```

or like this:

```bsh
Set-Location 'E:\Exxellence\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin'
(.\psql -U postgres -l) -match '^ \S' | ForEach-Object {
    ($_ -split '\s+\|\s+')[0].Trim()
} | Where-Object {
    $_ -match '^(beheer|forms|loket|kcs|mo|alfresco)$'
} | ForEach-Object {
    .\pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -f "${_}.backup" $_
}
```

and it should do what you want.

**Note:** The filter for the database names assumes that these are exact names. If they're only partial names change the line to `$_ -match 'beheer|forms|loket|kcs|mo|alfresco'`.

Comment: You obviously know PostgreSQL better than me , otherwise we are refining answers from input of the other. Wouldn't powershell try to interpret parameters to `.\pg_dump` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reaction!
the outcome of the .\psql is nothing?, your 3th point is exactly what i need, only the database names from the psql output

Comment: @LotPings `pg_dump` is an external command, so I wouldn't expect PowerShell to mess with simple arguments like that. But I've been surprised before. ^_^; Still, that would be my first take on the export, and I'd refine it if it actually produced an error.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thanks for the edit! but the output is still nothing, maybe something is wrong with ($_ -split '\s+|\s+')[0].Trim() ?? i have no idea what this does :P

Comment: @GlenHams It *should* split the lines of the table `psql -l` produces at pipes, pick the first token from each split line, and strip the remaining leading/trailing whitespace, leaving just the database name. What output does `(.\psql -U postgres -l) -match '^ \S'` give you? It should be only the lines starting with a database name.

Comment: I don't know the psql ouptut, but if the `|` is meant to be literal it needs to be escaped with a backslash `'\s+\|\s+'` otherwise it's an alternate `OR`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers (.\psql -U postgres -l) -match '^ \S' gives me al database names with all extra information, when i add the -split the output is nothing

Comment: @GlenHams See my updated answer. I had a typo in the split expression, as LotPings pointed out. It was supposed to be `\s+\|\s+`, not `\s+|\s+`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers & LotPings  Thanks! that helped! 1 more thing: when i add $_ -match '^(beheer|forms|loket|kcs|mo|alfresco)$' the output is again nothing. But then i remote the ^ and $ is gives me exactly what i want! Thanks guys for your help! ;)

Answer (score 0):

First issue with your PowerShell code is in foreach loop. Try this:

```
ForEach ($database in $databases)
```

And change name of $databases variable (1st line).